# Map-Reduce на C++ с использованием std::async

Tags: c++, многопоточность, stl, асинхронность, шаблоны-с++

Пытаюсь написать MapReduce.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename It, typename Func>
void map(It first, It last, Func f)
{
    while (first != last)
    {
        f(*first++);
    }
}

template <typename It, typename MapFunc, typename FoldFunc>
auto map_reduce(It first, It last, MapFunc f1, FoldFunc f2, size_t num_threads)
    -> decltype(f2(f1(*first), f1(*first)))
{
    size_t block_size = std::distance(first, last) / num_threads;

    std::vector<std::future<int>> results(num_threads);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        results[i] = std::async(map, first, last, f1);
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    std::list<int> ls = { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto sum = map_reduce(ls.begin(), ls.end(),
        [](int i) {return i; },
        std::plus<int>(),
        3);

    return 0;
}
```

Почему компилятор ругается на вызов `std::async`?

Как вообще реализовать эту концепцию, чтобы преобразование подпоследовательностей происходило в отдельных потоках, результаты потом сворачивались, и при этом исходная последовательность не изменялась?

Comment: Почему мы передаём в возврат f2 от двух результатов f1, каждый из которых взят для итератора на начало?

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете *шаблонную функцию* `map` в шаблон же, и компилятор не понимает, что туда надо подсунуть.

Можно попробовать так:

```
results[i] = std::async(map<It,decltype(f1)>, first, last, f1);
```

только вот у вас `results` - это фьючерсы `future<int>`, а ваша `map` возвращает `void`...

Если исправить и это, то скомпилироваться она [скомпилируется](https://ideone.com/Epq7vc), ну, а что она делать будет - это я не смотрел.